# Providing Function/Stored proc access to user in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a prototype database where I created a number of stored procedures and functions.

A peer needed to review the these and wanted to access. Both of us have `GRANT ALL` level privileges on the database, but we were unable to see each other's functions and stored procedures.

We eventually figured out that you need access to `GRANT SELECT on mysql.proc`. Why is this required?

I thought that for security reasons it may be assumed that it's not safe for an *invoker* to see the logic going on in a database that has *definer* rights. But this did not seem to resolve the restrictions.

Comment: Should I assume "because that's how it was designed" is not the answer you are looking for?  This is [documented behavior of `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-procedure.html).  If you don't own it, you can't see its definition, without  privileges on `mysql.proc`.  If you don't have the `EXECUTE` privilege on it either, then you don't even know it's there.  Other than that, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: It just feels like a very odd workround for me that someone who can do pretty much all changes to a database, needs access to a table in a different DB to really see everything that is going on. In our case we tie down access to analysts so someone working for a client A cannot see how what client B is doing with their data and even though I don't expect this to be an issue, in this instance by selecting the mysql.proc table, the users can now see all the logic in stored procs.